# Mongodb - make inmemory or use cache

Tags: performance, mongodb, caching, memory

I will be creating a 5 node mongodb cluster. It will be more read heavy than write and had a question which design would bring better performance. These nodes will be dedicated to only mongodb. For the sake of an example, say each node will have 64GB of ram.

From the mongodb docs it states:

> MongoDB automatically uses all free memory on the machine as its cache

Does this mean as long as my data is smaller than the available ram it will be like having an in-memory database?

I also read that it is possible to implement mongodb purely in memory

> http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/49304254688/how-to-use-mongodb-as-a-pure-in-memory-db-redis

If my data was quite dynamic (can range from 50gb to 75gb every few hours), would it be theoretically be better performing to design mongodb in a way which allows mongodb to manage itself with its cache (default setup of mongo), or to put the mongodb into memory initially and if the data grows over the size of ram use swap space (SSD)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB default storage engine maps the files in memory. It provides an efficient way to access the data, while avoiding double caching (i.e. MongoDB cache is actually the page cache of the OS).

**Does this mean as long as my data is smaller than the available ram it will be like having an in-memory database?**

For read traffic, yes. For write traffic, it is different, since MongoDB may have to journalize the write operation (depending on the configuration), and maintain the oplog.

**Is it better to run MongoDB from memory only (leveraging tmpfs)?**

For read traffic, it should not be better. Putting the files on tmpfs will also avoid double caching (which is good), but the data can still be paged out. Using a regular filesystem instead will be as fast once the data have been paged in.

For write traffic, it is faster, provided the journal and oplog are also put on tmpfs. Note that in that case, a system crash will result in a total data loss. Usually, the performance gain does not worth the risk.